# Бот на Python не работает в беседе VK

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

не так давно начал изучать Python в частности VK Api. Никак не могу добавить бота в беседу, чтобы он минимально реагировал на сообщения пользователей в чате. Перебрал все ответы пользователей на этом форуме по поводу этой проблемы, но скрипт либо не запускается либо не работает. Документация на сайте разработчиков ВКонтакте не менялась с 2019 года. Буду рад помощи!

Сейчас имею такой код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotEventType, VkBotLongPoll
from config import tok

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = [TOKEN])
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, [ID] )

def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

def chat_sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0})

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

        msg = event.object.message['text'].lower()

        if event.from_chat:
            id = event.chat_id
            chat_sender(id, msg.upper())

        else:
            id = event.object.message['from_id']
            sender(id, msg.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю разберёшься

```
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = "TOKEN") 
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def send(id, message):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': id, 'message': message, 'random_id': 0})
    
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:                              
            if event.from_chat:
    
                msg = event.text.lower()
                id = event.chat_id 
                
                if msg == "привет":
                    send(id, msg.upper())
                            
                else:
                    send(id, "Не поняла вашего ответа...")
```